# FB.UI using imaging staging

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a standard file-upload form, which I want to use to collect a user's image and than upload to Facebook.

If I post the upload form to the [FB 'staging' url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#images), I get the encoded staging reference - but when I try to launch a `FB.UI()` feed dialog, supplying the staging token as a "picture" parameter it fails?

Is the *staging URL strictly for use in creating a graph object w/o using the dialog*? And if I want do use the dialog *do I have to upload the image somewhere else and than reference it* ?

Here's my example:

```
$('#picture_upload').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('action',$(this).attr('action')+'?access_token='+accessToken);
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success:  function(response){
            FB.ui(
              {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                picture: response.uri,
                caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
              },
              function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                  alert('Post was published.');
                } else {
                  alert('Post was not published.');
                }
              }
            );
        } //call function after success
    });
});
```

The response contains something like:

```
{"uri":"fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDAxMDE1MTU3NjIyNzExNzYwNA=="}
```

Which is obviously invalid as a `picture` parameter in the `FB.UI` function